# Modify output of item from SimplePie using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using SimplePie to display the title of the first item from an RSS feed that is updated when something happens to a bill in a legislative body I've been asked to monitor. This legislative body publishes RSS feeds I can fetch with SimplePie and display for people who need the information. The SimplePie code is doing its job perfectly.

However, I would like to modify the output before it is echoed using preg_replace, to clean it up a little.

My original SimplePie code that works is as follows:

```
<?php $max = $feed->get_item_quantity(1); 
      for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++): 
          $item = $feed->get_item($x); 
?>
<?php echo $item->get_title(); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

I tried using this:

```
<?php $max = $feed->get_item_quantity(1); 
      for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++): 
          $item = $feed->get_item($x); ?>
<?php $str = '/([0-9]+) &#8211;/'; 
      $str = preg_replace('/([0-9]+) &#8211;/', '', $str); 
?>
<?php echo $item->get_title(); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

... but it's not modifying my output. It doesn't appear to be doing anything. I'm not getting errors but it's not working.

The actual output (which is just an item title) currently looks like this:

> 07 – March 1, 2013 – Passed to Rules Committee for second reading.

That two-digit number at the beginning is extraneous information. I want to eliminate it and the hyphen that comes after it, so the title would come out like this:

> March 1, 2013 – Passed to Rules Committee for second reading.

although, ideally, I think it should look like this:

> (March 1, 2013) Passed to Rules Committee for second reading.

Suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :-

```
$str = '07 – March 1, 2013 – Passed to Rules Committee for second reading.'; 
$str = preg_replace('/(^[0-9]+) –/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output :-

```
 March 1, 2013 – Passed to Rules Committee for second reading.
```

Your Code :-

```
    <?php $max = $feed->get_item_quantity(1); 
          for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++): 
              $item = $feed->get_item($x); ?>
    <?php $str = '/([0-9]+) &#8211;/';  <<======= your title string is regular expression here
          // assign your title string here  
          $str = preg_replace('/([0-9]+) &#8211;/', '', $str); 
    ?>
    <?php echo $item->get_title(); ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
```

Updated Code :-

```
    <?php 
                $max = $feed->get_item_quantity(1); 
                for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++): 
                        $item = $feed->get_item($x); 
                        $title_str = $item->get_title();
                        $title = preg_replace('/(^[0-9]+) –/', '', $title_str); 

                        $pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
                        $replacement = '(${1} 1, $3)';
                        $title = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $title);  
                        echo $title;  
                endfor; 
     ?>
```

For your desired output :-

```
$string = 'March 1, 2013 - Passed to Rules Committee for second reading.';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '(${1} 1, $3)';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Output :-

```
  (March 1, 2013) – Passed to Rules Committee for second reading.
```

Comment: Tried it (had to make the hyphen a single hyphen) and it works! What regex would you recommend to put parentheses around the date so it reads like this? (March 1, 2013) Passed to Rules Committee for second reading

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify your code like this, the $str  you have used should have contained the string you wished to modify.

```
<?php $max = $feed->get_item_quantity(1); 
      for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++): 
          $item = $feed->get_item($x); 
 echo preg_replace('/([0-9]+) &#8211;/', '', $item->get_title()); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```